# Naming of classes providing the complete implementation of an interface, but which are designed to be extended / used as mixins

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

If you write an interface with a lot of methods, say `IPerson`, and you expect a lot of different implementations of it, it is quite common practice to provide an abstract class `AbstractPerson` which implements the bulk of the functionality.

Normally `AbstractPerson` is abstract, since you usually leave some key functionality unimplemented. In this case the naming makes sense.

But what is a good naming convention in case you already implemented all of IPerson, but still expect subclasses? Perhaps `PersonMixin`, `PersonHelper`, `GenericPerson` or simply `Person`? I think `Person` is a bit vague, since it doesn't clearly show the intended usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is from the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) (for .NET), I think it applies equally to any language. The reccomendation is:

**Avoid naming bases class with the Base suffix if the class is intended to be used in public APIs.** If the library exposes the base class as a return type or parameter type, it should not have the Base suffix.

In general, if the class is public (or even private, although there is less risk in that case) and you name it `PersonBase` there is an implication that it is a base class. If at some point in the future the class hierarchy is refactored and `PersonBase` is no longer the base class you would want to rename `PersonBase` to something else which would most likely result in a breaking change for any consumer code.

I would simply name the class `Person` and let any derived classes use more specific names. I think `Person` is very clear and indicative of it's use as a generic (non-specific) person.

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting your answer since it's the one with the best motivation, although Stevens answer was pretty close to yours.

Answer (score 3):

I think `Person` is just fine. The whole point is that you might specialize it to specific types of people, but it's still a person.

Answer (score 2):

<s>If it can be used as-is, I'd stick with `Person`. If not, I'd make it abstract (even if it has no abstract members) and call it `PersonBase`.</s>

Comment: PersonBase may cause problems in the long term if the class hierarchy is refactored and `PersonBase` is no longer the base class. When that happens and you rename `PersonBase` and/or introduce a new `PersonBase` it has the potential to break downstream consumers.